# SQL Server : stored procedure to insert more than one row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-insert, bulkinsert

I have a table where you can request a number of devices.

`Request` table:

```
ID     noOfdevice    requestedby
--------------------------------
 1         4            sam
```

How can I create stored procedure or for the device table to insert 5 new rows for the devices as per noOfdevice column from the `Request` table?

`Device` table:

```
ID        requestedby
---------------------
dev1           sam
dev2           sam
dev3           sam
dev4           sam
```

Comment: MSSMS using ms sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop to run multiple insert statements. For MySQL:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/while.html

Here is an very short Pseudocode-Example:

```
counter INT =1 ;

SELECT noOfdevice
INTO var1
FROM Request table
WHERE requestedby= [NAME];

  WHILE counter <= var1 DO
       insert....
  END WHILE;
```

The exact Syntax may vary from different databases

Comment: What happens if the table you are inserting to has a HASH id